# Trigger dynamic loading of css

Tags: css

My javascript app adds at some moment an optional css file, with:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('link');
style.href = "fonts.css";
style.type = 'text/css';
style.rel = 'stylesheet';
head.append(style);
```

I thought that the styles defined in the added css were applied immediately, but they don't.

My problem is that I need to execute a function when those style are actually applied. How can I detect the moment when it happens?

Comment: Well the resource has to _load_ first of all. You could probably add a `load` handler to the link element you are creating there to wait for that, but not sure that will exactly match _"when those style are actually applied"_, because parsing the file might also take a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect when the styles have been applied. The best you can do is detect when the new file has been loaded. You can use `onload` event on the `link` element to execute code. Make sure you defined the event handler *before* setting href attribute - I have been caught by this before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches that might work, the first is using the most obvious choice of an event-listener to listen for the `load` event being fired on the created-element, as follows (with explanatory comments in the code):

```js
// caching the document in a variable with a shorter name (because I'm lazy, and
// don't like typing unnecessarily):
const doc = document,
  // a simple function to create and append an element, taking four
  // arguments:
  // what: String, the element-type you wish to create,
  // where: String, a CSS selector to find the element to which the created-
  //        element should be appended,
  // fn: function, the callback function to fire once the element is loaded,
  // props: Object, properties and property-values to apply to the created-
  //        element, with a default value of an empty Object literal:
  appendElementTo = (what, where, fn, props = {}) => {
    // using document.createElement() to create the desired element,
    // passing that created-element along with the props Object to
    // Object.assign() to add the given properties (if any)
    let creation = Object.assign(doc.createElement(what), props),
      // using document.querySelector() to retrieve the element to which
      // the created-element should be appended; this will return the first
      // matching element from the document (if such an element exists), or
      // null (if not matching element exists):
      target = doc.querySelector(where);

    // here we check that the target element exists, and use a Yoda condtion to
    // check that the target.nodeType is 1 (and is therefore an HTMLElement),
    // I use the Yoda condition because it's almost impossible to accidentally
    // use an assignment in place of a comparison:
    if (target && 1 === target.nodeType) {
      // if there is a callback function supplied:
      if (fn) {
        // we use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the callback function
        // aas the 'load' event-listener on the created-element:
        creation.addEventListener('load', fn);
      }

      // we use Element.append() to append the created-element to the
      // target element:
      target.append(creation);
    }
    // this function returns nothing to the calling context, you may wish to
    // add an explicit return in your use-case (but that's beyond the scope
    // of the current question).
  },
  // a simple function to demonstrate the callback working (this can be more
  // or less complex as you require to achieve your desired functionality):
  test = (evt) => {
    document.querySelector('body p:last-child').style.color = `red`
  };

// calling the function, passing in the Strings
// 'link' and 'head' (the 'what' and 'where' arguments respectively):
appendElementTo('link', 'head',
  // passing in a reference to the callback function (note the
  // deliberate lack of parentheses):
  test,
  // and, finally, an Object literal for the properties to apply to the created element:
  {
    // the element-property as the Object keys, and the element property-values
    // as the Object values (the search paramater and calls to Math.random() are to cause
    // the browser to load the resource on every run, rather than caching (in your own
    // use-case this may not be required, adjust to taste):
    href: `https://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/base.css?v=${Math.random()}.${Math.random()}`,
    type: `text/css`,
    rel: `stylesheet`,
  });
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Demo content</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus repellendus, eos itaque ab doloremque dolorum reiciendis ut, unde commodi. Esse, voluptatem dolorem sint ratione placeat quas, inventore non autem ullam aperiam quae minima eaque nobis
    eos. Voluptatum sunt perspiciatis ab illum tempora quam, odio voluptatem ipsam eaque amet, cumque animi aut, facilis quidem nihil quasi, vel rerum quaerat numquam vero deserunt earum ipsum. Voluptatem atque, quas provident. Voluptatum, expedita consequatur
    modi voluptate reiciendis, consequuntur nostrum laboriosam itaque suscipit magni dolorem maxime cumque unde facere, culpa animi, corporis nam necessitatibus? Nesciunt impedit aliquam molestias quos, consequatur, neque ad architecto quibusdam laborum
    optio dolores!</p>
  <p>Provident, voluptatum. Optio ut officiis nam ex debitis officia animi placeat dolorum inventore ipsa sapiente illum numquam doloremque assumenda libero a impedit laboriosam, ratione eveniet expedita, voluptates nihil est, perspiciatis. Nostrum magnam
    possimus fugiat dolor, quod repellat beatae porro? Delectus eaque minima facilis autem temporibus fugiat numquam impedit nisi aspernatur cupiditate reiciendis corporis, placeat totam, ipsa, commodi aut. Quam porro ratione dolor sunt est dicta sapiente
    molestiae adipisci eveniet dolorum assumenda pariatur deserunt vitae officiis, rem nostrum in recusandae doloremque repellat odit voluptatum, aperiam necessitatibus. Quia consectetur quod doloribus esse, tempore iusto, vel culpa ut, consequatur quas
    odit.
  </p>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3wety1f4/1/).

Alternatively, and this may be a little more cumbersome, you could use a CSS animation and – in JavaScript – listen for a `transitionend` event:

```js
// the linked CSS defines a keyframes animation on the <body> element, here we
// use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the anonymous function as the
// event-handler for the 'animationend' event (the event fired once the animation
// has ended):
document.body.addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
    // the functionality to be fired on completion of the animation, which - as the
  // animation is defined in the linked CSS stylesheet - should only run once the
  // stylesheet has loaded into the document and been applied:
  console.log("animation ended");
// in JS Fiddle this wasn't necessary, but here in SO the function kept getting called
// despite the animation-iteration-count being explicitly set to 1 (so the animation
// should have run only once). It is, however, a cheap guard against a memory leak; so
// here we use the options to cause the function to run only once:
}, {once:true});

const doc = document,
  appendElementTo = (what, where, props = {}) => {
    let creation = Object.assign(doc.createElement(what), props),
      target = doc.querySelector(where);
    if (target && 1 === target.nodeType) {
      target.append(creation);
    }
  };

appendElementTo('link', 'head', {
  href: `https://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/base2.css?v=${Math.random()}.${Math.random()}`,
  type: `text/css`,
  rel: `stylesheet`,
});
```

```css
/*

The content from the linked stylesheet, commented out to prevent this CSS being applied:

// defining the animation, specifying only the completion (this was the simplest do-nothing
// CSS I could think of):
@keyframes loadVerification {
  to {
    color: currentColor;
  }
}

:root {
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,body {
  min-block-size: 100%;
}

body {
  // only two parts matter; the animation defined above and the call to use that
  // animation:
  animation: loadVerification 0.1ms;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-block: var(--spacing);
}

main {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, hsl(150deg 90% 70% / 0), hsl(150deg 90% 70% / 0.6));
  block-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(20rem, 80%, 1200px);
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

p {
  margin-block: var(--spacing);
}

*/
```

```html
<link href="https://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<main>
  <h2>Demo content</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus repellendus, eos itaque ab doloremque dolorum reiciendis ut, unde commodi. Esse, voluptatem dolorem sint ratione placeat quas, inventore non autem ullam aperiam quae minima eaque nobis
    eos. Voluptatum sunt perspiciatis ab illum tempora quam, odio voluptatem ipsam eaque amet, cumque animi aut, facilis quidem nihil quasi, vel rerum quaerat numquam vero deserunt earum ipsum. Voluptatem atque, quas provident. Voluptatum, expedita consequatur
    modi voluptate reiciendis, consequuntur nostrum laboriosam itaque suscipit magni dolorem maxime cumque unde facere, culpa animi, corporis nam necessitatibus? Nesciunt impedit aliquam molestias quos, consequatur, neque ad architecto quibusdam laborum
    optio dolores!</p>
  <p>Provident, voluptatum. Optio ut officiis nam ex debitis officia animi placeat dolorum inventore ipsa sapiente illum numquam doloremque assumenda libero a impedit laboriosam, ratione eveniet expedita, voluptates nihil est, perspiciatis. Nostrum magnam
    possimus fugiat dolor, quod repellat beatae porro? Delectus eaque minima facilis autem temporibus fugiat numquam impedit nisi aspernatur cupiditate reiciendis corporis, placeat totam, ipsa, commodi aut. Quam porro ratione dolor sunt est dicta sapiente
    molestiae adipisci eveniet dolorum assumenda pariatur deserunt vitae officiis, rem nostrum in recusandae doloremque repellat odit voluptatum, aperiam necessitatibus. Quia consectetur quod doloribus esse, tempore iusto, vel culpa ut, consequatur quas
    odit.</p>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3wety1f4/2/).

Comment: the second version (using animation) works for me, but only if I set an animation longer than 50ms; values shorter than 50ms, don't work. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Not that I know of, @Paolo, sorry ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `onload` event to the link:

```
style.onload = myFunction;
```

and in myFunction you must wait for the document ready, i.e. (jQuery code):

```
function myFunction() {
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      // do what you need to
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't this solution work?